# Batch Rename all PNG files in folders and subfolders

Tags: powershell, batch, script, batch-rename

I am trying to rename all PNG files within several subfolders. See below for my explanation on what I am doing:

```
What is currently in place:
COMPANY
     SERVER1
         (Random).png
COMPANY2
     SERVER32
         (Random).png

What I want:

COMPANY
     SERVER1
         Company - Server1 - (Date PNG Modified).png
COMPANY2
     SERVER32
         Company2 - Server32 - (Date PNG Modified).png
```

How can I accomplish this? The part that I am having trouble with is getting the First and second directory name as well as the date modified that I can stick into the file name.

The current script that i have is below:

```
@echo off
for /r %%D in (.) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /A:-D "%%D\*.png"') do (
    echo ren "D:\FinalDir\%%F" "%%~nxD-VirtualBootTest-3-3-18.png"
)) >> "D:\FinalDir\RenameCommands.txt"


FOR /R "D:\OriginalDir" %%i IN (*.png) DO COPY "%%i" "D:\FinalDir"
```

What this is doing right now is gathering all of the PNG files in all directories in the folder that building a batch file to rename all of the files that it copies out into the FinalDir. The renaming end result will end up looking like SERVER1-VirtualBootTest-3-3-18.png. I cant figure out how to make the date change with the file and add what the directory is two directories above the file.

Answer (score 0):

So this script should do the trick.  It is relatively simple.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $basePath -File -Filter *.png -Recurse
foreach($file in $files){
    $pathParts = $file.fullName.split('\')
    $dateMod = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
    $first = $pathParts[-3]
    $second = $pathParts[-2]
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName "$first - $second - $dateMod.txt"
}
```

Here is the **breakdown** part by part:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $basePath -File -Filter *.png -Recurse
```

First it gets all the files starting from the base path **(You'll have to set the `$basepath` variable to your path)** recursively to the end of the structure.

```
foreach($file in $files){
    $pathParts = $file.fullName.split('\')
    $dateMod = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
    $first = $pathParts[-3]
    $second = $pathParts[-2]
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName "$first - $second - $dateMod.txt"
}
```

Then for each file it:

- Splits the file's fullname (path and file name) based on the '\' character.

  `$pathParts = $file.fullName.split('\')`
- Accesses the lastWriteTime and formats it to the format you want.

  `$dateMod = $file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")`
- For the `$first` and `$second` variables it is accessing the path that has been split from the right side (-1 would be file name, -2 is parent, -3 is parent of that parent and so on).

  `$first = $pathParts[-3]`

  `$second = $pathParts[-2]`
- Takes all that information gathered and renames the file to those pieces of info collected.

  `$file | Rename-Item -NewName "$first - $second - $dateMod.txt"`